# jquery get not working for https page

Tags: javascript, jquery

from

https://test.com/customers/?test.html

test.html

```
$('#myDiv').get("https://test.com/service/customers/index.html?name=jbloggs");

<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

I get no data return or errors if I add function call

but if I run the same url call in browser I get the html page back

Anyone have any idea why get or load have this issue

Comment: What do you expect to receive? Are you handling rewrites on the server?

Comment: Is your script in a document ready, or after the markup?  Because as you have it in your question, it is not and it is before the element it is trying to change.

Comment: I've never heard of an overload to [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) that takes a URL...

Comment: I have this part in both document ready and in function areas neither return the HTML back to the div, and it doesn't matter if its a get or load neither return the HTML back

Answer (score 2):

I feel like you are actually wanting to use load.

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>

$('#myDiv').load("https://test.com/service/customers/index.html?name=jbloggs");
```

$.get() is just a basic ajax get request.  If you want it to put the result in an element automatically, that is load()

Comment: As I said above load doesn't return data either and no errors report

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for you help turns out its a IE11 issues

Its resolved if I use firefox or edge